# Printing results from an array seperately from user input in java

Tags: java, arrays

So I'm trying to create a program that takes in the student's GPA and prints out if they are graduating at an honor's level, graduating, or not graduating. I have most of the code figured out, but I am trying to make it so that ALL of the input is first, and then it will go back and print out whether each student is graduating. But what I am getting is printing out the graduation status for each student immediately after the input for that student.

I'm getting this:

```
Enter the number of GPAs: 3
GPA #0: 3.99
Student #0: Summa Cum Laude
GPA #1: 3.1
Student #1: Graduating
GPA #2: 2
Student #2: Graduating
```

When I want this:

```
Enter the number of GPAs: 3
GPA #0: 3.99
GPA #1: 3.1
GPA #2: 2
Student #0: Summa Cum Laude
Student #1: Graduating
Student #2: Graduating
```

Here is my code:

```
    System.out.print("Enter the number of GPAs: ");
    int size = sc.nextInt();

    int array[] = new int[size];
    double gpa;


    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        System.out.print("GPA #"+ i + ": " );
        gpa = sc.nextDouble();

        if (gpa >= 3.90) {
            System.out.println("Student #" + i + ": Summa Cum Laude");
        } else if (gpa >= 3.70) {
            System.out.println("Student #" + i + ": Magna Cum Laude");
        } else if (gpa >= 3.50) {
            System.out.println("Student #" + i + ": Cum Laude");
        } else if (gpa >= 2.0) {
            System.out.println("Student #" + i + ": Graduating");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Student #" + i + ": Not graduating");
        }
    }


}}
```

Comment: Are you aware that the array you created is not being filled with values, ​​and this leads to the conclusion that the array is filled with 0 ,and in for loop you are not doing any action in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to fill the array with values `GPA` we declare an array of double

```
double array[] = new double[size];
```

We iterate through for loop and we ask user to enter GPA and we fill our array with those values

```
 for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.print("GPA #" + i + ": ");
            gpa = sc.nextDouble();
            array[index++] = gpa;

        }
```

Now we have array with our values filled so what should we do know we print it by checking array values with our if statements.

```
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        if (array[i] >= 3.90) {
            System.out.println("Student #" + i + ": Summa Cum Laude");
        } else if (array[i] >= 3.70) {
            System.out.println("Student #" + i + ": Magna Cum Laude");
        } else if (array[i] >= 3.50) {
            System.out.println("Student #" + i + ": Cum Laude");
        } else if (array[i] >= 2.0) {
            System.out.println("Student #" + i + ": Graduating");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Student #" + i + ": Not graduating");
        }
    }

    }


}
```

**FULL CODE**

```
System.out.print("Enter the number of GPAs: ");
        int size = sc.nextInt();

        double array[] = new double[size];
        double gpa;
        int index = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.print("GPA #" + i + ": ");
            gpa = sc.nextDouble();
            array[index++] = gpa;

        }


        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            if (array[i] >= 3.90) {
                System.out.println("Student #" + i + ": Summa Cum Laude");
            } else if (array[i] >= 3.70) {
                System.out.println("Student #" + i + ": Magna Cum Laude");
            } else if (array[i] >= 3.50) {
                System.out.println("Student #" + i + ": Cum Laude");
            } else if (array[i] >= 2.0) {
                System.out.println("Student #" + i + ": Graduating");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Student #" + i + ": Not graduating");
            }
        }

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to have one list of GPA's immediately followed by another list of status'. If that is the case, then you have 2 separate lists, which will require 2 separate loops.

Make a loop that prints out your GPA's, then after that loop finishes, have another loop that prints out the status'. Also, you will need some way to store those values from the first loop. Maybe an array?